# Magento2 - Add mailchimp popup

Tags: magento2, javascript, mailchimp

we have Magento 2.1.7ce and would like to add the MailChimp popup to our homepage.

We currently don't have access to the FTP/SSH so we have to do this with the cms pages.

When i add this code to a CMS page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us7.list-manage.com","uuid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","lid":"xxxxxxxxxxx"}) })</script>
```

And access the firebug console sees it's trying to load files from the static files:

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://server.com/static/frontend/Theme/customtheme/nl_NL/mojo/signup-forms/Loader.js

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - https://server.com/static/frontend/Theme/customtheme/nl_NL/dojo.js"
```

How can I fix this? Or is it not allowed to use JavaScript in cms pages?

Answer (score 1):

Mailchimp uses [dojo](https://dojotoolkit.org/) for managing required modules and dependencies.

Line

```
require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us7.list-manage.com","uuid":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","lid":"xxxxxxxxxxx"}) })
```

conflicts with the RequireJS, that is used in Magento.

You can use Mailchimp Embedded forms instead of the Subscriber pop-up and use [Modal widget](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/javascript-dev-guide/widgets/widget_modal.html) for embedding form into popup

Answer (score 0):

Magento allow to use JavaScript in cms pages.

I tried your js, the `//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js` js loaded well.

The problem is **lacking** `dojo.js`.

If you don't have access to the ftp/SSH, you could upload the dojo.js to `s3.amazonaws.com`, then load it like `embed.js`,

like

> `<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/the-path-to/dojo.js" >
>   </script>`

After you load `embed.js`, if it still doesn't work, use the develop tool(Chrome is F12) to find the problem. I guess the `"mailchimp popup"` function need several js files, you doesn't upload and use them completely.

Comment: Any solution for this fix ?

Answer (score 0):

I've built the modal popup and it all works.

Structure includes calling a block called `newsletter.php` which has return `'Dummy Content'` in it.

Question is,

> I've got the embed form code from my mailchimp account by I don't know
>   how to add that to a block in M2 or should I scrap the block and just
>   add it into the `newsletter.phtml` file?

I'm a bit confused

Answer (score 0):

conflicts with the RequireJS, that is used in Magento so that we can use different code try below code which works well

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/unique-methods/embed.js"
        data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(mailchimp, 2000);
  function mailchimp() {
    window.dojoRequire(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) {
      L.start({
        "baseUrl": "mc.xxx.list-manage.com",
        "uuid": "xxxxx",
        "lid": "xxxxx",
        "uniqueMethods": true
      })
    })
  }
</script>
```